# How does session.load() method of pulls up the data without hitting the database?

Tags: java, hibernate, session, orm

When we call session.get() method hibernate will hit the database and returns the original object.

When you call session.load() method, it will always return a “proxy” object without querying the database.

My question is if load() method is not hitting the database then how it know whether the requested information is available in the database.

Comment: It doesn't until you actually try and read it.

Comment: then what is the benefit of using load()? I was looking for the difference between get() and load() but the context is this everywhere.

Comment: No this is not the JPA API, so kindly dont tag it as that

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have parent child association. For example, there is one master table. You are injecting reference of one object into other object.

Consider a student class. Many students belongs to same standard of school.

Here one to many relationship is generated between standard and students.

Now while saving student object you will need persistent object of standard.

you will have to persist student object as below:

```
student.setStandard(standard);
```

Now, you have primary key of standard object. And you knows that this standard is already exist in database. For now consider that it is a master table. So rather than actually hitting the database, you are making fool that there is already one object:

```
Standard standard = session.load(Standard.class, id);
```

So hibernate will not hit the database and it will create a proxy object that will you inject in your student object. and when you will call session.save(student) at that time it will be saved.

But suppose you are loading Standard object using load() method. and if you will try to call any method on that like standard.getClassTeacher() then it will actually hit database and if it is not found in db then it will throw error.